# Event-delegate analogy in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have WinForms app with MVC pattern implemented, where Model is running asynchronously (backgroundWorker thread) from View (Form). View is subscribed to couple of events that are raised from Model.

Now I need to convert this to WCF app, where event-eventHandler concept has to be present.
At first, I wanted to implement this via callback interface, but in my case one method from Model is raising more than one type of events, and I am constrained on usage of single callback interface when defining service contract.

At this moment I came up with the idea of specifying different type of events as methods in callback service and implement it in client.  For example:

```
public interface ICallbacks
{
  [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
  void EventHandler1();

  [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
  void EventHandler2(string callbackValue);

  [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
  void EventHandler3(string callbackValue);
}
```

Should I go along with this solution or there are some better alternatives (publish-subscribe wcf pattern)?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you definitely want pub/sub architecture here.

Take a look at Juval Lowy's Publish-Subscribe Framework from this MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use single method with a base type parameter to activate your call. Then in your service code, jump to specific handler based on the type of the event.

```
public class BaseEvent { }

public class MyFirstEvent : BaseEvent { }

public class MySecondEvent : BaseEvent { }

public class MyThirdEvent : BaseEvent { }


public interface ICallbacks
{
  [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
  void EventHandler(BaseEvent myEvent);
}

public class MyService : ICallbacks
{
   public void EventHandler(BaseEvent myEvent)
   {
      //Now you can check for the concrete type of myEvent and jump to specific method.
      //e.g.: 
      if (myEvent is MyFirstEvent)
      {
         //Call your handler here.
      }


      //Another approach can be predefined dictionary map of your event handlers
      //You want to define this as static map in class scope, 
      //not necessarily within this method.
      Dictionary<Type, string> map = new Dictionary<Type, string>()
      {
         { typeof(MyFirstEvent), "MyFirstEventHandlerMethod" },
         { typeof(MySecondEvent), "MySecondEventHandlerMethod" }
         { typeof(MyThridEvent), "MyThirdEventHandlerMethod" }
      };

      //Get method name from the map and invoke it.
      var targetMethod = map[myEvent.GetType()];
      this.GetType().GetMethod(targetMethod).Invoke(myEvent);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Duplex is not a good idea unless your application runs on the same at least on the same network and there are not proxies, etc to interferer with. You will also end up with a tight coupling between publisher and subscriber.